# Export existing custom Activity fields to metadata xml

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api

I have a salesforce DX project and I need to add some custom fields that have already been created in Salesforce to the project. They are custom Activity fields. I realize I can create a new file under `force-app/main/default/object/Activity/fields` with a metadata representation of these fields in my project but is there a way to generate these files since the fields already exist in salesforce?

If so is it possible to do this with other metadata like RecordTypes, Lightning pages, and Event layouts?

Comment: Doesn't pulling from the org fetch your new metadata. Please refer to sfdx force:source:pull command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following commands:

For the entire Activity object: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Activity`

For specific field within Activity object: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -p "c:\Users\<Actual Path>\force-app\main\default\objects\Activity\fields\<Field API Name>.field-meta.xml"`

For all lightning pages: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m FlexiPage`

For specific lightning page: `sfdx force:source:retrieve -p "c:\Users\<Actual Path>\force-app\main\default\flexipages\<Lightning Page Name>.flexipage-meta.xml"`

**Instead of using the commands, a much easier way to do this is to use the `ORG BROWSER: METADATA` in Visual Studio Code**. You can drill down in the org browser and retrieve a specific component or file (see screenshot below).

[image]

When retrieving a specific file or component this way, you can also get the corresponding exact SFDX command in the `Output` pane (see screenshot below). You should have `Salesforce CLI` selected in the drop down in the top right corner.

[image]

---

*Note that, in order to be able to do this, you should have authorized the org in VS Code. You can do this by `Ctrl+Shift+P` (windows) > select `SFDX: Authorize an Org` > Choose the appropriate org type and follow the steps entering the credentials in the login web page (that opens up in browser).*

While [SFDX CLI reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm#cli_reference_pull) is the definitive guide, it doesn't list out the specific commands for every single component or file or type available in SF. So, if you want to retrieve specific file (such as field metadata xml) or want to pull set of files via SFDX commands, you can pull one another file (of required type) using org browser and get the command from the output pane. You can also get specific command while retrieving data from the `EXPLORER` pane. For example (as shown in screenshot below), if you retrieve a specific field, you can get the corresponding SFDX command from the Output pane.

[image]

This way you can figure out the commands for specific metadata types (such as event layouts, record types etc.) & overcome any limitations retrieving via VS code org browser or for additional flexibility in retrieving.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I'm looking for thank you.